# Why such heavy computation is turning off my computer?

Tags: shutdown

I am running this script:

```
import pyspark
import random

sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName="Pi")

num_samples = 100000000

def inside(p):     
  x, y = random.random(), random.random()
  return x*x + y*y < 1

count = sc.parallelize(range(0, num_samples)).filter(inside).count()
pi = 4 * count / num_samples
print(pi)
sc.stop()
```

And it's working without any issues.

If I increase the `num_samples` variable to `1000000000` for example, after like 2 seconds my computer shutdown completely.

cpu: amd 5950x
64gb RAM
gpu: RTX 3070 TI
psu: CV 750W Bronze

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: there are basically three common reasons a blackscreen shutdown might occur: a thermal problem, a power problem, or an unhandled exception in an unlucky part of kernel code. if it happens in seconds right after a cold start where the system has been off for a while, its likely a power issue. check the power rails to your video card. make sure you have rails plugged in to all the pins available on the card. also make sure your rails for the CPU are correctly connected. you may also want to try it when plugged into a different wall socket, as you may be getting dirty or insufficient power

Answer (score 2):

You most likely have a CPU cooling problem.  Push it hard, it overheats and goes into thermal shutdown.

Check fans etc.  The last time it happened to me the culprit turned out to be a failure of the pump for a liquid cooling system.

Answer (score -1):

A 750w psu doesn't seem like enough.
A amd 7700x and 5700 gpu and it wasn't enough.

The 12v volt rail kept dropping below the minimum value as soon as it was under load.